# NLP transformers and classification interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, logistic, interpretation, transformers

I have an NLP transformer output and build logistic regression on top of it to classify negatives and positives.
How can I see how the prediction was made on a large set of data? What if I use a neural network instead of a logistic regression? I’m curious which words/sequences of words affect the prediction the most.

Comment: How are you using logistic regression to classify a sequence? You have to reduce the sequence to a fixed-length vector; how do you do this? And are you freezing the Transformer parameters and using it only for feature extraction, or are they updated during training? It’ll affect my answer.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I'm following this example: https://jalammar.github.io/a-visual-guide-to-using-bert-for-the-first-time/